# Minisplit Install With Thin-Walled Lineset

Tags: air-conditioning, mini-split, copper-tubing

I'm currently installing a multi-zone minisplit in my home.  Unfortunately, I bought the cheapest linesets I could find.  The 1/4" line has thinner walls and is very difficult to flare and torque down.  The nuts keep stripping the flare when I try to torque to specs.  If I torque to less than spec, and the lines still hold pressure, would there be any long-term detrimental effect to the system?
I also heard that I should replace all flare nuts with thicker ones.  Is that necessary?

Comment: Are you lubricating the nuts?

Comment: One of the most common fatal problems with mini-splits is leaking refrigerant. The lineset is not an area to be cheap with. Can you replace with better quality?

Comment: Yes, nylog on all nuts.  Thanks for answers.

Comment: If you torque to less than spec, and the lines still hold pressure, then you stop because you're done. When it fails, don't call me back because it's flare fittings in the first place. Those go in RVs on gas lines because they have to, and no where else. "I should replace all flare nuts [that they gave me] with thicker ones?" apparently that's a yes, if you're actually going to use a torque range, instead of the intuitive, *that's good. Any more will break it.* - We're talking 400 psi, not even solder will suffice. Why isn't it just brazing? Because it's DiY? YMMV....

Comment: Flare is up to 5000 psi. Brazed connections are up to 70,000 psi... I'd throw them away and braze it. But is there some reason you're supposed to use flare fittings on mini splits?